# member receives role when joining discord

Tags: python, discord.py

Got a simple code that gives a role to members when they join the server. For some reason, it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Players")
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

Doesn't give any errors, am I missing some sort of perms?

Comment: did you enable members intent?

Comment: Just enabled the "Server member" intent on discord developers but it doesn't seem to work still

Comment: you also have to enable them in your code.

Comment: How do I do that sry?

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html#where-d-my-members-go

Comment: I've added in the intents code and enabled it on discord developers, I can't tell what else I'm doing wrong